# Windows Forms - Integer being reset upon form load

Tags: c#, winforms, integer

My issue is that an integer created in my main class,

```
public int loadCountGold = 0;
```

that is incremented to when a button triggering the appearance of another form

```
public void goldButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadCountGold += 5;
    Console.WriteLine(loadCountGold);
    GoldForm gForm = new GoldForm();
    gForm.Show();
}
```

Is not having its incremented value carried over to the form where it needs to be used in an if statement.

```
private void GoldForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    //Sets the random (within reason) value for gold
    if (main.loadCountGold <= 1)//if its the firstload of the form
    {
        Console.WriteLine(main.loadCountGold);
        Random rand = new Random();
        currentGoldValue = rand.Next(1200, 1350);    
    }
}
```

I had included a few write lines at points before the form is opened, and one within the problem form to see what was happening to the value. This can be seen below

[image]

It shows the output that my program is giving, highlighted are the outputs from my "Main" class and the other are the ones being produced from the problem form.

The aim is to have the value incremented each time the form is opened so that the code within the if statement is only run the first time the form is opened, but currently it is running every time. (I am aware I would need to change the amount it is incremented)

Comment: What is `main`? Is this a static variable of your main class?

Comment: You must be closing the form.  Instead make the form invisible.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: is this application is console app or winforms app?

Comment: Yes, it's just an instance of my main class

Comment: How exactly do you declare `main` in `GoldForm`? Like `MainForm main = new MainForm()`?

Comment: Main main = new Main();

Comment: currently I'm pressing the form "x" button to close it, are you saying if I create a button that just hides it instead it will fix it?

Comment: Your problem is that it is an instance. Somewhere somehow your GoldCount needs to be static. See my answer

Comment: Well, there's the problem. You have to pass the main form to your gold form, because right now you are always declaring a new instance of the main form, and by doing that, you always create a new int `currentGoldValue`, which of course is 0.

Comment: yeah closing the form isn't the issue. The problem is that the `loadCountGold` in your second block of code is not the same variable as in your first block of code because it is from a new instance of the main class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue of needing a static variable rather than one instanced with the class. The easy answer is to change your integer declaration to:

```
public static int loadCountGold = 0;
```

now all references to this variable will point to the same thing.

I should specify that your reference in the later form needs to be Main with a capital M.

```
if (Main.loadCountGold <= 1)//if its the firstload of the form
```

Comment: While you're at it, you might want to make your `rand` a static variable in your main class too. No need to re instantiate the object, calling `.Next()` will get you a different random number.

Comment: I can't refer to a static variable through a class instance though

Comment: ha, I just addressed that before you wrote. See my edit, you just need a capital M so for static variables you reference the `Class.Variable` instead of `Instance.Variabe`

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your main form, call `GoldForm` like this:

```
GoldForm gForm = new GoldForm(this);
```

In the constructor of `GoldForm`, do it like this:

```
Main main;
public GoldForm(Main main)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.main = main;
}
```

Now you don't create a new instance of `Main` every time you click the button.

Output after 3 button clicks:

```
5
10
15
```